# How do I Whitelist my web domain for gapi?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I added my  http://johndog.herokuapp.com    to 
Authorized JavaScript origins.
I am getting a an error not a valid origin.
It works from my localhost but not from the web.

Any suggestions?

TIA
FxM

I am  getting
"Not a valid origin for the client:  http://johndog.herokuapp.com  _.com has not been whitelisted for client ID 838458623675-29k9sdcckggqc5p1b07uh7r4ap0rmec7.apps.googleusercontent.com. Please go to https://console.developers.google.com/ and whitelist this origin for your project's client ID."
error: "idpiframe_initialization_failed"

Answer (score -1):

I had to add to both.
Authorized JavaScript origins
   https://johndog.herokuapp.com
Authorized redirect URIs
   https://johndog.herokuapp.com